# vscode debugger step in, step out

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a custom vscode debugger and have modified the mock debug example debugger project for my needs, and have so far got break points, continue and step over working. For continue and step over I was able to modify the protected continueRequest and protected nextRequest functions, which trigger when the respective buttons (during a debug session) are pushed. I can't seem to find any functions relating to "step in" and "step out", both default buttons shown during debugging. Also, is it possible to disable these buttons if my debugger does not support them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'mock debug' is just an educational debug adapter and I did not implemented `stepInRequest` and `stepOutRequest` because they would not add any new insights over the `nextRequest`.

If you want to implement them, just override the `stepInRequest` and `stepOutRequest` methods of the base class `DebugSession` (that means add the `stepInRequest` and `stepOutRequest` methods to your DebugSession subclass by copying them from the base class https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node/blob/master/adapter/src/debugSession.ts).

It is not possible to disable the 'step in' and 'step out' buttons but if you deem this functionality as important please file a feature request.